# Issue with registering the Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet to OSGI core Service Registration in Bundle Activator

Tags: spring-mvc, osgi-bundle

Using Bundle Activator,trying to register the Spring MVC's Dispatcher Servlet to Service Registration, but the

> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open
>   ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/helloworld-servlet.xml]     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:118)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:328)

Bundle Activator:

```
public class Activator implements BundleActivator {

private static BundleContext bundleContext;
private ServiceRegistration registration;

public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {

    Activator.bundleContext = context;
    try {

        ClassLoader old = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();

        Hashtable props = new Hashtable();
        props.put("alias", "/spring5");
        props.put("init.message", "Hello World!");
        props.put("contextConfigLocation", "/WEB-INF/helloworld-servlet.xml");
        props.put("contextClass", BAC.class.getName());
        props.put("sling.servlet.extensions", new String[]{"html", "jsp"});
        props.put("sling.servlet.methods", new String[]{"GET", "POST"});
        props.put("sling.servlet.resourceTypes", "examples/sling/spring/mvc/dispatcher/global");


        try {
            Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());
            this.registration = context.registerService(Servlet.class.getName(), new DispatcherServlet(), props);

        } finally {
            Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(old);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

}

public void stop(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
    this.registration.unregister();
}

public static BundleContext getBundleContext() {
    return bundleContext;
}

public static void setBundleContext(BundleContext bundleContext) {
    Activator.bundleContext = bundleContext;
}
}
```

Whereas BAC class :

```
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;
public class BAC extends org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext {

private BundleContext bundleContext;

public BAC() {
    super();
    setBundleContext(Activator.getBundleContext());

}

public void setBundleContext(BundleContext bundleContext) {
    this.bundleContext = bundleContext;
}
}
```

.

```
MANIFESH.MF INCLUDES:Spring-Context: /WEB-INF/helloworld-servlet.xml
```